# How to get the first part of this string using Google Sheets or SQL

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a string like "**AA_BB_CC_EEE**_FF_GGG".
Instead of these letters there can be any letters or numbers

How I can get the first part of this string "AA_BB_CC_EEE" using Google Sheets or SQL with the following conditions:

- the number of characters up to EEE is different (for example I have *BBBBB* in the midle);
- I know all possible variants of 3 characters EEE;
- the EEE always consists of 3 characters.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your end_of_first_part of string saying up and till the characters EEE?

Comment: Does your first bullet point mean you can also have values **without** the underscores? e.g. `AABBBBBEEE`? Or is it **always** two characters followed by an underscore followed by two characters followed by an underscore followed by two characters followed by an underscore followed by three characters? Or is it always the string up to the fourth underscore?

Comment: You said `I know all possible variants of 3 characters EEE;`. What are all these possible variants?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your three known variants of `EEE` are `EEE`, `EEF`, and `EEG`, this Google Sheets formula will do it with `AA_BB_CC_EEE_FF_GG` in cell `C35`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C35, "^(.*(EEE|EEF|EEG)).*$", "$1")
```

It yields: `AA_BB_CC_EEE`

In PostgreSQL it is similar:

```
select regexp_replace('AA_BB_CC_EEFfjdkaljfkal', '^(.*(EEE|EEF|EEG)).*$', '\1');

 regexp_replace
----------------
 AA_BB_CC_EEF
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use pretty long/complicated Google sheet formulas you can setup your own custom function in Google Apps Scripts. Open the script editor from your spreadsheet file. Clear the basic file and copy the following function:

```
function Process(input) {
var res = input.indexOf("EEE");
var final = input.slice(0,res+3);
return final;
}
```

Then you can apply this custom function to the desire input in the same way as you apply the other functions:

```
=Process(A1)
```

This will give you back the desired output:

*AA_BB_CC_EEE*

Please follow these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) if you need more information how custom functions work. They are pretty straightforward.

[image: Click on the Tools -> Script editor to add the function and then simply type =Process(A1) to use it]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, "_")), 9^9, 4)),, 9^9))), " ", "_"))
```

[image]